# Optimization problem of angles for classical mechanics problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, classical-mechanics, numerical-optimization

I come from civil engineering background but the problem I came across is more mathematical, so I seek your help here.

Imagine there is force to be supported using truss structure. Given is the location of the force in terms of **L3** , the value of a force **F** . From mechanics and trigonometry, it is possible to set up some restraints and force-balance relations which are shown in below figure.

[Image for Illustration [not able to embed due to reputation score]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3vFi.png)

The goal is to find the optimal angle alpha and theta (sum of absolute values of forces in member is minimum, so there is less net force to carry), which satisfies all equations. I struggle to find solution, only solution I can think of is trial and error but I think there has to be mathematical solution. Any suggestions are welcome.

UPDATE 1: After some time thinking about the problem, I have come with four equations, out of which two are restraints, in particular, force-balance gives:

(1) $-F+\frac{F*tan(\alpha)}{cot(\theta)+tan(\alpha)}+\frac{F*cot(\theta)}{cot(\theta)+tan(\alpha)}=0$

(2) $\frac{2*F}{cot(\theta)+tan(\alpha)}=0$

On the other hand, forces in members are given by $F$ and geometry as follows:

(3) $F_{BC}=\frac{F}{(cot(\theta)+tan(\alpha))*cos(\alpha)}$

(4) $F_{AC}=\frac{-F}{(cot(\theta)+tan(\alpha))*sin(\theta)}$

So basically, I need all solutions of equations (1) & (2), for which $|F_{BC}+F_{AC}|$ is minimum. In some sense it is optimization problem and I think only way to solve this is numerically, but unfortunately I am no expert in that field, so I need your help and explanation. This is as far as I can go with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question as written, but you may want to reconsider the question.

Equation $(1)$ is not a constraint at all. Equation $(2)$ is impossible to satisfy
if $F \neq 0.$ This makes sense as the only constraints really should be
the range of angles at which one can attach a member to the wall.

According to Equations $(3)$ and $(4),$

$$ F_{BC}+F_{AC} = \frac{F}{\cot(\theta)+\tan(\alpha)}
\left(\frac1{\cos(\alpha)} - \frac1{\sin(\theta)}\right). $$

Given the geometry of the problem, assuming $L_3 > 0$ and $H > 0,$
neither of the function values $\cos(\alpha)$ or $\sin(\theta)$ can be zero,
and $\cot(\theta)+\tan(\alpha)$ cannot be zero, so the right side of this equation
always as a value.

The minimum value of $\lvert F_{BC}+F_{AC}\rvert$ is then zero, which is achieved when
$\dfrac1{\cos(\alpha)} = \dfrac1{\sin(\theta)}.$

So all we have to do to optimize your criterion is to make the truss an isosceles triangle with its base on the wall. Any isosceles triangle with altitude $L_3$ from its base will do equally well, even the triangle created by setting $H = 0.001 L_3$.

But if we have an isosceles triangle with $H = 0.001 L_3$, the forces in the members will be much, much larger than $F.$ I doubt that this was the intent.

Are you perhaps trying to minimize $\lvert F_{BC}\rvert + \lvert F_{AC}\rvert$?
But this also is problematic. You can make $\lvert F_{BC}\rvert + \lvert F_{AC}\rvert$
as close to $F$ s you want by choosing $\theta$ close enough to $0$
or $\alpha$ close enough to $\frac\pi2$ (that is, $90$ degrees),
but you cannot make $\theta = 0$ or $\alpha = \frac\pi2$ exactly,
so you cannot make $\lvert F_{BC}\rvert + \lvert F_{AC}\rvert = F$ exactly.
Also, this approach leads you to make $H$ larger and larger without bound in order for the sum of magnitudes of forces to approach $F$.

Is there perhaps some other constraint? For example, a predetermined value of $H$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $L_1,L_2, F$ known, by statics we have

$$
F_{AC}(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)+F_{BC}(-\cos\alpha,-\sin\alpha) = (0,-F)
$$

but

$$
\cases{\sin\theta = \frac{L_3}{L_1}\\ \cos\alpha = \frac{L_3}{L_2}}
$$

Solving now for $F_{AC}, F_{BC}$ we have

$$
\cases{
F_{AC} = -\frac{F L_1}{L_1 \sqrt{1-\frac{L_3^2}{L_1^2}}+L_2 \sqrt{1-\frac{L_3^2}{L_2^2}}}\\
F_{BC} = \frac{F L_2}{L_1 \sqrt{1-\frac{L_3^2}{L_1^2}}+L_2
   \sqrt{1-\frac{L_3^2}{L_2^2}}}
}
$$

then

$$
\min_{L_3}\{|F_{AC}|+|F_{BC}|\} = F\ \ \ \text{for}\ \ \ L_3 = 0
$$